# Highcharts show menu buttons alongside blank title

Tags: highcharts

When you remove the title by setting text to ''

```
 title:{
        text:''
    },
    subTitle:{
        text:''
    }
```

all is good and you hide the title. However, if you see the context menu button, it is [in the chart area](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/284/show).

I need to show the menu button [in the line of chart title](http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/JVNjs/286/show) but with a blank title. Just a visual enhancement and nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JVNjs/453/

Use a `marginTop` in the chart options:

```
chart: {
    marginTop: 40,
    renderTo:'container',
    borderWidth:1,
    plotBorderWidth:1
},
```

Comment: Ok. That should do it. Thanks